# Binding Control Properties to BindingSource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, bindingsource

How can I bind the Property (Location.X) of a C# button to a BindingSource?

I have tried the following code

```
myButton.DataBindings.Add("Location.X", myButtonsBindingSource, "Button_X");
```

but it is not working, it works for example if I want to bind the Text property of the button but not for X & Y coordinators.

any ideas or other ways to bind Location.X property of my button to a binding source programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: Not much in the way of details but you could try binding `Location` instead of the `X` portion which is usually read-only

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp Actually Location.X is not read-only because I can change it's value programmatically, however as you said binding Location property is working but Location.X is not, made me confused.

Comment: Use `Left` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Left`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.left?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property of the button instead:

```
myButton.DataBindings.Add("Left", myButtonsBindingSource, "Button_X");
```

Above statement creates a data-binding between `Button_X` property of the object which you have in `DataSource` of `myButtonsBindingSource` and `Left` property of `myButton`.